# How can emacs preview java jmod file like jar file from dired?

Tags: emacs

They are both zip file actually. I can preview jar file directly from dired, but not for jmod files.

I can view jar files like this after opening jar files from dired.

[image]

I tried adding `jmod` to `dired-compress-file-suffixes`, not working.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'dired-compress-file-suffixes '("\\.jmod\\'" "" "unzip -o -d %o %i"))
```

by the way, `jar` is not in `dired-compress-file-suffixes` too.

Comment: Not a programming question; see e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20833/how-to-deal-with-zip-archives-in-dired (in particular the snippet about `dired-compress-file-suffixes`)

Comment: n.b. Emacs as a tool in general is on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: After more discussion (see comments), we've established:

- `*.jmod` files are a (slightly) different file format to `*.jar` files, in that the magic characters at the beginning are `JM` vs the `PK` used in jar files (and in zip files more generally).
- Were it not for that, the suggested config changes below would actually be unnecessary, as the zip file detection in `magic-fallback-mode-alist` would handle them.
- As it is, it's necessary to not only tell Emacs that these are archives, but additionally to modify the `archive-find-type` function to recognise what *kind* of archive they are, as this function currently only recognises the `PK`-based zip file format.

For files starting with `JM^C^D` (as rendered by Emacs), the following change to `archive-find-type` should do the trick (but I don't know whether that's sufficient):

```
@@ -772,6 +772,7 @@
   ;; as an archive by other software.
   (let (case-fold-search)
     (cond ((looking-at "\\(PK00\\)?[P]K\003\004") 'zip)
+          ((looking-at "JM\003\004") 'zip)
           ((looking-at "..-l[hz][0-9ds]-") 'lzh)
           ((looking-at "....................[\334]\247\304\375") 'zoo)
           ((and (looking-at "\C-z")     ; signature too simple, IMHO
```

*Original answer follows...*

---

The default `auto-mode-alist` contains the following entry for `archive-mode`, with a regexp that matches `.jar` files:

```el
("\\.\\(arc\\|zip\\|lzh\\|lha\\|zoo\\|[jew]ar\\|xpi\\|rar\\|cbr\\|7z\\|squashfs\\|ARC\\|ZIP\\|LZH\\|LHA\\|ZOO\\|[JEW]AR\\|XPI\\|RAR\\|CBR\\|7Z\\|SQUASHFS\\)\\'"
 . archive-mode)
```

The docstring for that variable also says:

```
The extensions whose FUNCTION is `archive-mode' should also
appear in `auto-coding-alist' with `no-conversion' coding system.
```

Hence this should do the trick:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jmod\\'" . archive-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-coding-alist '("\\.jmod\\'" . no-conversion))
```

Comment: tried with no luck.

Comment: Does "preview jar file directly" mean something different than "visit file in Emacs and see the zip archive contents, and from there be able to select individual files to visit inside Emacs?"

Comment: I added a picture in my question.

Comment: N.b. I've assumed that a *.jmod file is the same format as a *.jar file, as you said they were both zip files.  My test was copying a *.jar file to a new *.jmod name.  If this isn't working for "proper" jmod files,perhaps your test files are not actually the same format.  I suggest testing the way I did, for starters.  And in fact, I've realised that `magic-fallback-mode-alist` detects my test cases by default, so I won't be surprised if it turns out that the format is not the same.

Comment: Right, we're talking about the same thing then.  Your picture is what I see with my test cases, which are *.jar files renamed as *.jmod files, so I suspect your *.jmod files are a different file format to *.jar files.

Comment: If you can provide a URL for a *.jmod file, I could test with that.

Comment: You are right, magic characters of jmod files are `JM` while jar files are `PK`. But according to oracle's specification like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jmod.html, it's a zip file, or at least zip-based. And I can uncompress jmod files from dired by pressing `Z` after setting `(add-to-list 'dired-compress-file-suffixes '("\\.jmod\\'" "" "unzip -o -d %o %i"))`

Comment: In conjunction with `M-x find-function RET archive-find-type` that would explain it.  I expect a workaround will be to use a custom definition of that function.

Comment: got it, seems like that's hard-coded.

Comment: If that's actually an official zip file format, it should be added to the standard `archive-find-type` function (please `M-x report-emacs-bug`).  If it's not a standard zip format, some research might be needed to find out whether or not it's safe to trust that any file with those contents is going to be a zip file; but I figure Emacs could still trigger archive-mode for jmod filenames if that's a reliable association, in which case `archive-find-type` support would still seem a valid enhancement.